# while vs for R looping: how to get similar results on two loops

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I have heard and read that there are significant speed advantages to using `for` loops rather than `while` loops in R.  If that is the case, I want to use for loops as much as possible.  However, I have unbalanced panel data (some cross-sectional data have more observations recorded than others).  So I need loops that are flexible in the number of observations it skips between cross-sections.  As an example, I might have one household that has observations for 2 years, and another household that has observations for 4 years.  Here is some trivial code that shows what I mean:

```
set.seed(123456)
##25 cross-sectional units with varying number of yearly observations
m1 <- matrix(c(rnorm(60),rep(2,20),rep(4,20), rep(2,20), 
               rep(seq(10), each=2) , rep(seq(11,15), each = 4), 
               rep(seq(16,25), each = 2)), ncol=3)
##colnames(m1) <- c("x1", "#_of_Obs", "Panel_ID")
v1 <- as.numeric()
v2 <- as.numeric()
id1 <- as.numeric()
id2 <- as.numeric()

for(i in 1: (nrow(m1))){
  counter <- m1[i, 2]
  v1 <- c(v1,i)
  id1 <- c(id1, m1[i,3])
  i <- i + counter
}

i <- 1
while(i <= (nrow(m1))) {
  counter <- m1[i, 2]
  v2 <- c(v2,i)
  id2 <- c(id2, m1[i,3])
  i <- i + counter
}     

v1; id1 # for loop inaccurate
v2; id2 # while loop accurate
```

Is it because of the `in` command that the `for` loop doesn't work?  If not that, how do I go about changing the for loop to work?  Also, is the difference in speed between the for/while loop exaggerated?  I know in the trivial data it doesn't matter, but I'm dealing with real data and thousands of observations.

Comment: Any difference there may be between for and while loops (and I seriously doubt there is) will be swamped by the obscenely inefficient code you've written inside each loop, that grows objects by concatenating them.

Comment: Learn to use R functions that handle irregular row counts within groups: `tapply`, `ave`, `by`, `lapply(split(, ), )`, `aggregate` ... and of course the 'plyr' family .

Comment: @DWin, thank you for the comment.  I'll look at those.  I'm trying to revise some code written in another statistical language into R.  Their code is very basic and they use a lot of do-until loops.  This for loop won't do what I'm trying to ask it to do, but I don't understand how to get it to do so.  I'm still trying to operationalize the code in R. I don't want to use repeat loops, so I thought converting things into for loops would be helpful.  Just don't know how to yet.

Comment: @Tony it may be more beneficial for you to provide some sample data that can illustrate some or all of the problem you are attempting to solve. Generally (but certainly not always) `for` loops are not very `R` like, because there are *usually* vectorised alternatives that will be much *much* faster, but one cannot tell without further information. Also in your `for` loop every time you start a new iteration you reset `i` to the row number of the current iteration, whereas `i` is cumulative in the `while` loop.